How to Resolve Google cloud and Firebase "Organization Policy Restricts Users from Specific Domains" Error?
The owner of our firebase DB projects is unable to add me to google cloud and Firebase projects due to the following error: "An organization policy restricts that only users from specific domains are allowed. Please contact an organization admin."
he sent me an invitation to join as an editor, but when I try to accept it, I got the same error. Does anyone knows how to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Domain Policy error
What I tried:

Confirmed with the project owner that I was invited with the correct email address.
Retried accepting the invitation multiple times.
Searched Firebase documentation and forums for similar issues.
Asked the project owner to review their organization policy settings.

What I expected:
I expected to successfully join the Firebase projects and gain access as an owner.

Have you read the documentation about domain policies?

Yes, I read the documentation and followed their directions yet facing the same issue
